# Query Filtering Corresponding Columns

Tags: google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

Formula work in progress:

```
={query(C3:G82,"select * where D like '1' order by C desc, D asc LIMIT 1",0);query(C3:G82,"select * where D like '2' order by E desc LIMIT 1",0);query(C3:G82,"select * where D like '3' order by D asc, F desc LIMIT 1",0)}
```

Resulting output goal:
The three highest values are chosen from column C. Values output to column L where column M has 1,2,3 listed only once each, where column N has 1,2,3 listed only once each, where column O has 1,2,3 listed only once each and where column P has 1,2,3 listed only once each.

My output so far:
Everything seems to work out for column M and column N. Unclear what I may be missing or my next steps.

Link to sheet:
[linktosheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F870aDIoJJimQsrzGWaIsT4TbwstlHHmiLk-5kOAT3c/edit)

Thank you,
David